# Connect to PostgreSQL online DB using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh-keys

I am currently connecting to a PostgreSQL DB using [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

However I want to **connect to DB directly with Pyhton**, so that I can automatize the data flow.

I have the following information field given (Just giving the headers here):

**SSH:**

- Host/IP:
- User Name:
- Authentication Method: Public Key
- Private Key: (have a file)

**Main PostgreSQL DB connection settings:**

- Host: [....]amazonaws.com
- Database:
- Authentication: Database Native
- Username:
- Password:

I have only READ permission.

How to connect setup connection to DB using python?

I have tried with pyodbc, but am getting an interface error

```py
import pyodbc
server = '[...] amazonaws.com' 
database = 'something' 
username = 'user_name' 
password = 'xyz' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

OUT:

```py
--> 17 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
     18 cursor = cnxn.cursor()

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There are several good Python packages for Postgres, including `psycopg2`.  If you need an ssh tunnel, that will have to be separate.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think my confusion is how I enter Parameters to connect. I have insalled pyodbc, but have struggled to get further.

Comment: Ok so SSH tunnel needs to be separate, with a different package

Comment: You're not thinking about what you're doing.  You are trying to open a connection to SQLServer, but you said you were using Postgres.  If you intend to use `pyodbc`, then you need to read about connection strings for Postgres.